# iOS 9 - Why aren't select inputs in a UIWebView working in split screen mode?

Tags: uiwebview, ios9, hybrid-mobile-app, multitasking, selectlist

We have an app that we are currently upgrading to work in iOS multitasking split screen views.  Everything is working great, except for select lists within our UIWebView.

In full screen mode, the select list works as expected. However, in split screen mode when the user clicks the select input, a list pops up covering the entire app. When an option on the list is selected, the list clears, but the blank list is not dismissed.  The only way to dismiss the blank list is to pull the app into full screen mode once again.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Does anyone have any potential solutions? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open bug in iOS 9.2. Source https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23300

Comment: i have posted some details on that problem https://medium.com/@chemm/select-inputs-on-ipad-breaking-third-party-browsers-in-slide-over-or-split-view-1-3-952b796d70ad#.p16xxhn82